# I need help finding algebraic area and perimeter, please

Tags: area

Could you help me solve some or all of the problems please? I can't understand the procedure for solving them...

solve the following problems determines algebraically the perimeter and area of the following questions

***sorry if i did something wrong i'm new and i don't understand english very well***
[image]

Thank you for your attention, it would be a pleasure if you could answer my question

Comment: In these perimeter and area questions, you are effectively being asked to add or multiply the dimensions together to get the resulting quantity.  For example with a width of $3n$ and a height of $2n$ the resulting area would be $3n\cdot 2n=6n^2$ and the perimeter would be $3n+2n+3n+2n=10n$.

Comment: ahhhhh I think I understand a little

Comment: thank you for everything

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to edit the question or ask a new one if there is a more specific issue you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1

note that we know how to solve the area and perimeter of a rectangle, a square being a unique version of this solution. I.e. $A=Width * Height , P=2*Width + 2*Height$

Rectangle 1: (note that all squares are rectangles, so technically this is correct)

$p= 2*3m+2*3m = 6m+6m = 12m $ , $A = 3m*3m = 9m^2$

Rectangle 2:

$p= 2*2n+2*3m = 4n+6m$ , $A= 2n*3m $

Rectangle 3:
$p=2*2n+2*2n=8n$ , $A=2n*2n = 4n^2$

Rectangle 4 (the large unmarked square) Is using the information on the previous examples
to formulate the same type of answer (note that you could also use the expressions that we have created to calculate the perimeter and area, I shall use this way but it is worth you trying to form it like I did for the smaller squares to see if you get the same answer)

$P=\frac{r_1+2r_2+r_3}{2} = \frac{12m+2(4n+6m)+8n}{2} = \frac{24m+16n}{2} = 12m+8n$

$A=r_1+2r_2+r_3 = 9m^2+2(2n*3m)+ 4n^2 = 9m^2+(4n*6m)+4n^2$
$A=(3m+2n)^2$

I would suggest looking at the last "collection' of shapes to see if you can apply the same reasoning as I did for the first three. If you can, have a think why I was able to do it differently.
I hope that answers your question

Comment: Thank you very much for your time I needed the answers, thank you very much